# Matplotlib - x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (37,) and (38,)

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

This is my code:

```
Y1 = a1_points['pontos_num']
Y2 = a1_points['RollingAvg']
Y3 = a2_points['pontos_num']
Y4 = a2_points['RollingAvg']
X = max(len(Y1),len(Y3))

plt.plot(range(1,X), Y1, label='Vitor Gabriel Gameweek Points', lw=0.5, ls='--')
plt.plot(range(1,X), Y2, label='Vitor Gabriel Rolling Average', lw=3, color=Blue)
plt.plot(range(1,X), Y3, label='Luis Henrique Gameweek Points', lw=0.5, ls='--', color=Amber)
plt.plot(range(1,X), Y4, label='Luis Henrique Rolling Average', lw=3, color=Amber)

plt.xlabel('Rodada')
plt.ylabel('Pontos')
plt.title('Vitor Gabriel vs. Luis Henrique')

plt.xlim(1,X-2)
plt.ylim(0,15)

plt.legend(loc=2, frameon=False);
plt.show()
```

---

how do I fix the error?

Comment: I think for each plot, you can try `plt.plot(range(1, len(Yn)+1), Yn, ...)` where n is 1, 2, 3 or 4

Comment: nailed it.  if you answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `range(1,X)` doesn't have the same length than Y1 and/or Y3 because the way you build it. If both `a1_points` and `a2_points` have the same same length, then `range(1,X)` should be replaced by `range(1,X+1)`. But in the case `a1_points` and `a2_points` don't have the same length, then it safer to do:

```
plt.plot(range(1, len(Yn)+1), Yn, ...)
```

for each n is 1, 2, 3 or 4 in your case